# SSIS Deployment : The task <task name> cannot run on this edition of integration services. It requires a higher level edition

Tags: sql, service, ssis, integration, bids

My SQL Server Database Engine is installed on a remote machine and the Development Tools(BIDS and SQL Server Management Studio) is installed on my local machine.

Using BIDS, I have created a SSIS package. It runs without any issue when executed from BIDS (By pressing F5). But, when I deployed this package onto the SQL Server and tried to execute it from SQL Server Management Studio, it gave me the following error :

**The task `<task name>` cannot run on this edition of integration services. It requires a higher level edition.**

After a little research, I found that the version of Integration Services installed with Database Engine on remote machine is different from what is installed with Dev. Tools on the local machine.

Also, the SQL Server is an Enterprise Edition whereas, the BIDS on local machine is Professional Edition.

1) Are the above 2 facts possible reasons for this error?
2) What are the ways (other than Tool upgrade) to get rid of this error?

Thanks

Comment: Professional edition refers to the Visual Studio installation. SQL Server, which uses SSIS, would have *editions* of Express, Developer, Standard, Enterprise, Datacenter, and Business Intelligence. Your BIDS environment uses the Developer edition which provides access to all the features of Enterprise edition (minus some maximum cpu count IIRC) but licensed in a cost effective manner. Not to be confused with edition, there are also *versions* (2005, 2008/2008 R2, 2012) of SQL Server to contend with. Local might have 2008 but server is still 2005.

Comment: In the sql agent job history, post the first line of detail. It should be something like `Executed as user: DOMAIN\USER. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 10.0.4000.0 for 64-bit`  Then open up any of the packages and right click on the background of the control flow and select Properties. We need to see what is listed for PackageType (DTSDesigner100, 90, 80) etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where qre you running the package from? Bear in mind that the package is run on the box that called it, not the one xhere it is stored.

Also you said: `that the version of Integration Services installed with Database Engine on remote machine is different from what is installed with Dev`
I think thats the issue, you cant run a package built on 2008 on a 2005 server

Answer (score 1):

On the remote server create a foolish import export pkg with the wizard in ssms and save the pkg some where... do the same on the dev machine and the open the pkgs with notepad and look to the difference in the headers (usually the problem is there).

Ex of a 2008 pkg

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><DTS:Executable xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts" DTS:ExecutableType="SSIS.Package.2">
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="PackageFormatVersion">3</DTS:Property>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="VersionComments"></DTS:Property>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone!!!

Here is what worked for me :

When we run the package by right clicking it in the Object Explorer(in SSMS), the package runs on the machine where we start it. It does not run the package on the server machine. We either need to install SSIS on the machine where we are trying to run the package from, or run the package on the server machine directly.

[Reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dataaccesstechnologies/archive/2009/12/11/you-get-error-code-dts-e-productleveltolow-while-running-package-outside-business-intelligence-development-studio.aspx)

I executed the package on a different dev machine (with SSIS installed), and it worked!!!